# Issue when adding BibTex entries to .bib file

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using RStudio and the R package `bookdown`. I am having issues when trying to add a new bibtex entry to a .bib file.

In my index.Rmd I have the following line:

```
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
```

I added a new entry to packages.bib and then I built the book with the "Build Book" button in RStudio (I tried HTML and PDF). When opening the book in html or pdf, the citation looks like `"???"`. When I close packages.bib and open it again, the entry that I added is not there anymore. Furthermore, when I make a change to any of the .bib files (just adding a space) and then saving the following error is displayed:

```
Error in if (config$output_dir != ".") exclude <- c(exclude, config$output_dir) : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I tried cleaning the project and building it again but that did not solve the problem.

**Versions:**

- OS: Windows 10
- R: 3.6.1
- RStudio: 1.2.1335
- bookdown: 0.12
- rmarkdown:1.14
- knitr:1.24

Comment: This sound a little like a file permission issue. Have you tried saving the bib as a new file and changing the lines in your index.Rmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default `bookdown` project the file `packages.bib` [is dynamically created](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/f08a6f178f455918f3147b8aa3595c459c07aed9/inst/rstudio/templates/project/resources/index.Rmd#L30-L33) to contain citation information for the specified R packages only. Use `book.bib` for adding BibTeX entries by hand.